# Can I set grid-auto-rows to be the same as grid-template-row so they can have the same height?

Tags: css, css-grid

I tried to find any answer on google but it seems that no one had the same question, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: set only grid-auto-rows

Comment: It would be nice to see what have you tried so far or an example of the code you are trying to modify so this way we could give a better response, although sounds like the comment above nailed it.